# The web server process that was being debugged has been terminated by Internet Information Services (IIS). How to resolve it?

Tags: asp.net, iis

**The web server process that was being debugged has been terminated by Internet Information Services (IIS)**

After every 1-2 minute I got above error and application get stop. And I am not able to debug the application. How to resolve this? Or how to increase time period for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Solution 1:***

Launch IIS manager > right-click application pool of the website -> click on advanced settings -> scroll down to process model section -> increase the **Ping Maximum Response Time**.

***Solution 2:***

Launch IIS manager > right-click application pool of the website -> click on advanced settings -> scroll down to increase process model section -> Set **Ping Enabled** to **False**.